# Shell script invocation error in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode

I've the following problem: I'm using Xcode 9.1 to build my Swift apps. Since a few days I got the error

```
shell script invocation error
```

everytime I want to compile the project. It's the only error which is displayed.

I already read some threads here and followed the instructions. F.e. I uninstalled CocaoaPods and reinstalled the latest version, I cleaned up the project, the right scheme is selected etc. But I can't get it to work.
Or is it maybe a problem that I have no iCloud keychain configured? A message with the question to store the "access" key was displayed once but I don't know if this is a problem of Xcode.

Comment: do you have pod installed ?

Comment: Yes I've reinstalled it.

Comment: Could you please do the following 1. Update your `CocoaPod` to the latest release version and 2. Use this lib `(https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate)` to deintegrate pod and install again.

Comment: Cocoapods is already on the latest version. The solution was to activate the keychain option in my iCloud account. I don't know why this is strongly necessary now...

Answer (score 0):

Tried it with:-

pod deintegrate

pod install